# How to get password using combination of other columns?

Tags: vba

I need to find or get password from below Excel data based on combination of Fname and Lname. I tried to use Index Match with multiple criteria but it seems to be not working. I need this formula in VBA only, not Excel formulas.

[image]

Comment: You’re missing a lot of information needed to help you. Share your attempt as well

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot below refers.

If you don't have Office 365, then enter formula in first cell (here, D3) and press 'ctrl', 'shift', 'enter'.  Otherwise simply enter and press enter (spill effect will take care of rest).

Caveat/disclaimer: FName + SName is relatively 'weak' lookup - given two individuals can have same first and last name, or the 'database' containing all pw's may include names with initials, spelling inconsistency, Title (Mr/Mrs).  The solution proposed here does 'light weight' format adjustment (using 'Proper'), if you are convinced/satisfied re: both lists containing consistent formatting, you can drop this component of the equation (i.e. remove Proper and assoc. brackets as req.).

**Function**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($K$3:$K$8,MATCH(PROPER(B3:B8&C3:C8),PROPER(I3:I8&J3:J8),0)),"NOT FOUND!")
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot illustrating setup]

Linked sheet [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98Bn_7QT6lTsG30CT?e=ayJmgD) for your convenience.